# Time out de un Store Procedure consumiendo un API en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, api, stored-procedure, timeout

espero me puedan ayudar

Tengo un `Stored Procedure` en `SQL Server` que se encarga de hacer un llamado a un `API`. (Sé que no es lo mejor pero así me lo solicitaron) he notado que cuando se deja de enviar notificaciones la conexión pareciera entrar en reposo, entonces la primera notificación falla y genera un **time out**.

Cuando hago la llamada al *SP de notificación*, agregué un `while` que si no me responde el `estatus 201` que genera la respuesta exitosa, lo vuelva a intentar hasta 3 veces. Este ciclo se cumple si los intentos llegan a 3 o sí la respuesta es diferente a 201.

Solicito su apoyo para ver que puedo agregar a la condición en el `while` o si lo hago con un `if` para leer si da `time out` lo vuelva a intentar ya que no manejo mucho la programación en `SQL`.

Espero me pueda ayudar, gracias!!

```
WHILE(@w_intentos <= 3 and @w_retorno <> '201' )
    BEGIN
        EXEC @w_retorno = bd_ct_virtual..sp_notifica 
            @i_ref      = @w_referencia,
            @i_ref_z    = @w_referencia_z,
            @i_fecha    = @w_fecha,
            @i_amt      = @i_mont,
            @i_name     = @i_men
        
        SET @w_intentos  = @w_intentos  + 1
    END
UPDATE bd_virtual..bv_mk_log
SET mk_intentos = @w_intentos
```

Dentro del sp_notifica se hace el llamado a un ensamblado que hace el envío al API, aunque uno de los parámetros que envío es el time out, quisiera saber que hacer si se cumple el time out

```
select @w_retorno = bd_ct_virtual.dbo.postJson(
                    @w_url, 
                    @w_poststr,
                    '',
                    @w_contenttype,
                    @w_metodo,
                    3000, -- time out
                    @w_authorization)
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Tu pregunta, es para mi interesante por la implementación que hiciste (que definitivamente debe ser refactorizada a futuro). Ahora; no has dado detalles de la implementación en si: ¿Desarrollaste el consumo de la API en un ensamblado de .NET que luego portraste al motor de base de datos SQL server (con las caracteristicas de integración CLR que posee)? En tal caso el manejo se traslada .Net y no a sql serve. ¿O el timeout lo deseas manejar rn T-Sql? Whatever be, sin vcodigo alrededor de la sentencia con la que invoca la API, no es posible para nadie darte sugerencias.

Comment: No code, no party. Ve a [edit] y nos cuentas más sobre esta implementación con código. Está interesante la pregunta!

Comment: La gestión del timeout iría en el llamado como tal. Es decir, dentro de `bd_virtual..sp_notifica`. No?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo lo puedo hacer dentro o si es posible allí en el mismo while mejor

Comment: Hola @MauricioOrtega ya agregué un mayor detalle, espero pueda ser de ayuda

Comment: Es que la cosa es saber cómo está hecho el llamado para saber cómo responder al evento. Si `postJson` dice algo _diferente_ cuando da timeout, pues es fácil poner algo en el while; si simplemente espera y dice 400 o 404, pues eso es lo que iría en el while. Recuerda que nosotros no conocemos ningún detalle de tu implementación :) No nos pongas a adivinar, porfi

Comment: `sp_notifica` hace mas cosas (consultas o llamados a otros sp) ?  Porque creo que el `while` que intenta colocar para realizar una invocacion persistente de la API que invoca `bd_ct_virtual.dbo.postJson` deberia estar al interior de `sp_notifica` alrededor de la invocación a `bd_ct_virtual.dbo.postJson` y no como lo tiene, alrededor de la invocación a `sp_notifica`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes incluir una espera dentro del ciclo para darle oportunidad a que el proceso "despierte":

La siguiente instrucción se esperará 10 segundos:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10:000' --Se espera los segundos especificados
```

Te quedaría algo así:

---

```
WHILE(@w_intentos <= 3 and @w_retorno <> '201' )
    BEGIN
        EXEC @w_retorno = bd_ct_virtual..sp_notifica 
            @i_ref      = @w_referencia,
            @i_ref_z    = @w_referencia_z,
            @i_fecha    = @w_fecha,
            @i_amt      = @i_mont,
            @i_name     = @i_men

        ----------------------------------        
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10:000'
        ----------------------------------

        SET @w_intentos  = @w_intentos  + 1
    END
UPDATE bd_virtual..bv_mk_log
SET mk_intentos = @w_intentos
```

Comment: El WAITFOR DELAY me funcionó sin embargo el endpoint tenía también un método GET para probar la conexión, así que cambié la lógica y hago el llamado a ese y allí es donde coloqué el WAITFOR DELAY, si es exitoso llamo al POST